# Cheaper alternatives to 99Designs.com (outsource CSS design)

Tags: website-design

I'm designing my own website as a side project and I want the site to look professional. (Read, not designed by a programmer.)  I don't mind spending a little money to have a professional do it, but design sites like 99designs.com cost way to much. (~$500+)

Is there a cheaper (~$100 - $200) alternative for getting a designer to improve an existing site? (Things like updating the CCS or suggesting better ways for laying out the navigation.) Or is my best bet trying to pick up a freelancer on Craigslist?

Comment: I've been using http://www.templatemo.com/ as a free source for neat, professional-looking HTML templates for small projects.

Comment: John Conde designs all sites on his own, he does not need these services. :-)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If it doesn't need be unique (or heavily branded), I use a place like themeforest.net

Comment: +1 this is great they have also admin control panel tamplate. Thanks for sharing!!!

Answer (score 3):

At the price you're talking about your options are going to be limited and the quality of work you get may be less then desirable. Good designers don't work cheap but they give you good value for your money.

You could try craigslist for sure but being that is trafficked by US visitors more then anything else I doubt you'll have much luck there. I'd see if you could find design and development forums that let you post job availabilities. They tend to be trafficked by international members which is your best bet to reach the price you're hoping for.

Answer (score 2):

What about [www.templatemonster.com](http://www.templatemonster.com), would be these cheap enough for you (still not uniques).

But graphic art, as stated by the word itself is an "art", and it's very subjective, what I might like so much, it might be something taht you totally dislike. So it's good to have at least 3/4 possible design to choose among, and 99design.com gives you exactly this, therefor it might be worth the price.

Answer (score 2):

[www.designonclick.com](http://www.designonclick.com) is always an option.

Comment: Very interesting! Less expensive than 99designs.

Answer (score 1):

Using **themeforest** and **templatemo** (already mentioned in previous answers).

I was actually looking for 99designs and agree that quality cost. If the price is the only factor then: http://fiverr.com maybe?